# Jersey web services

Tags: java, maven, jersey, java-web-start

I am trying to set up a simple Java web application using jersey for web services. However I have de following problem.
The tomcat server can’t find the resource http://localhost:8081/OnlineShop/rest/books/list but it can find my simple servlet http://localhost:8081/OnlineShop/index

[image: Problem]

I have the following web.xml 
[image: web.xml file]

In the other hand I noticed that com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer is present in my project because I added the dependency using maven however jersey.config.server.provider.packages is not present. Maybe that is the problem but I don’t know the exact dependency which I have to add.

My BookRest.java has the following code and is on the com.shop.rest package.

[image]

Finally my pom.xml has the following dependencies.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please, please get rid of this whole project. You're obviously a beginner and seem to be just putting random configurations and dependencies together, maybe from different tutorials. Your dependencies are incompatible and your web.xml configuration is wrong. Like i said, scrap the whole project and start from scratch. If you are just beginning, you should use one of the startup apps.

You're in Netbeans, so just do the following

1. File → New Project
2. Maven → Project from Archetype
3. Search `jersey-quickstart-webapp`
4. Select the one with the Group ID `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes`
5. The latest version should be displayed.
6. Should be self explanitory from there

You will that the only dependency added is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
    <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
</dependency>
```

And the web.xml will look something like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.stackoverflow.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will get you a simple app up and running. You will see a dependency that you need to un-comment for JSON support. Un-comment it. Or better yet, un-comment it, then change `jersey-media-moxy` to `jersey-media-json-jackson`. Jackson is IMO a better JSON library.

Also keep the [Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html) handy for some good reading and reference material for working with Jersey

Comment: Yes, you have the reason I was trying with some dependencies randomly. However I solved my problem using org.glassfish.jersey.core only. But could you explain me why org.glassfish.jersey.core is different from com.sun.jersey.core dependency because I supposed that com.sun.jersey.core is the official one and enough for a simple project.

Comment: `com.sun` is Jersey 1.x `org.glassfish` is Jersey 2.x The two are completely incompatible. You should never mix the two. Ever!